Python: Cannot get attribute from superclass
I know is a pretty basic question, but I've tried for hours and still can't figure it out why I cannot access the attributes of a parent class. My code:
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue_list = []

    def put(self, val):
        self.__queue_list.insert(0, val)

    def get(self):
        if len(self.__queue_list) == 0:
            raise QueueError
        else:
            val = self.__queue_list[-1]
            del self.__queue_list[-1]
            return val

class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        Queue.__init__(self)

    def isempty(self):
        li = Queue.__queue_list
        return bool(len(li))

- when running:

que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty():
        print(que.get())
    else:
        print("Queue empty")

I get the error AttributeError: type object 'Queue' has no attribute '_SuperQueue__queue_list'
I've also tried using super()or in the child class replacing li = Queue.__queue_list with li = self.__queue_list
Nothing works

Whenever you are naming an attribute with a two underscores, python name mangles the name of the variable. If I'm not mistaken, it mangles to: _Queue__queue_list in this case. To access it, use self._Queue__queue_list.

double underscore attributes and methods are obfuscated to keep them private to the class: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

The issue here is that you're trying to access the __queue_list attribute directly from the Queue class, which is not allowed since it's a private attribute. Private attributes in Python are "name-mangled" to avoid naming conflicts, which is why you're getting the AttributeError.

Does this answer your question? What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?

@EmanuelL you got it right, thanks!

@Aaron not really private, rather, exposes them mangled in a well-documented way that is accessible to everyone

@OscarCastro just use a single underscore. Why are you using two?

The issue here is that you're trying to access the __queue_list attribute directly from the Queue class, which is not allowed since it's a private attribute. Private attributes in Python are "name-mangled" to avoid naming conflicts, which is why you're getting the AttributeError
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue_list = []

    def put(self, val):
        self.__queue_list.insert(0, val)

    def get(self):
        if len(self.__queue_list) == 0:
            raise QueueError
        else:
            val = self.__queue_list[-1]
            del self.__queue_list[-1]
            return val

class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def isempty(self):
        return len(self._Queue__queue_list) == 0

# Usage
que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty():
        print(que.get())
    else:
        print("Queue empty")

Alternately you can use super() also:
def isempty(self):
    return len(super().__queue_list) == 0


a better solution would be to just not use double-underscore name-mangling

The error arises because of name mangling in Python. When you define an attribute with two leading underscores (like __queue_list), Python modifies the name to include the class name.  This is intended to prevent accidental name clashes in subclasses.
In your case, the attribute __queue_list in the Queue class is actually renamed to _Queue__queue_list. Here's how to fix your code:
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue_list = []  # This is now _Queue__queue_list

    # ... (rest of the Queue class remains the same)

class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()      # Use super() to properly initialize parent

    def isempty(self):
        li = self._Queue__queue_list  # Access the mangled name directly
        return bool(len(li))

# ... (rest of your code)

Explanation of Changes

super().__init__():  Always use super().__init__() to initialize the parent class correctly in the subclass constructor. This ensures proper attribute inheritance and avoids potential issues.

Accessing Mangled Name:  To access the attribute in the SuperQueue class, you need to use its mangled name, self._Queue__queue_list.  This way, you're directly referencing the attribute as it exists in the parent class.


Why Other Attempts Failed

li = Queue.__queue_list: This tries to access the attribute as a class attribute, but it's an instance attribute and was mangled.
li = self.__queue_list: This would work if you hadn't used double underscores, but because of the mangling, it's looking for a different attribute (_SuperQueue__queue_list) that doesn't exist.

Alternative: Protected Attributes
If you want to allow access to the attribute in subclasses without the name mangling, use a single leading underscore (_queue_list). This is a convention indicating that the attribute is "protected," meaning it should generally be accessed within the class or its subclasses, but not from external code.
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue_list = []  # Protected attribute
# ...

Key Takeaways

Double leading underscores trigger name mangling.
Use super().__init__() for subclass initialization.
Access mangled names directly with _ClassName__attribute_name.
Consider using a single leading underscore for "protected" attributes.

